# Where do POST request from a form send the data to in django

Tags: python, html, django

Suppose I have created a login page and a register page. both have forms with same name attribute say "username" in the input tag. login page calls views.login function and register page calls views.register function. Now in register page I am submitting a form with some username and saving it in a variable in views.register something like this
`username = request.POST["username"]`
views.login too have the same code
`username = request.POST["username"]`
My query is where will the username go? only in the views.register function or in views.login function too?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Yes, each view will have a value in `username` variable. Most likely in `views.register` you're going to be sending that value to be inserted to the database, and in `views.login` you're going to query if that value appears in the database presumably.

Comment: Forms have the ```action``` attribute. When you submit the form, it will be submitted to the url in the ```action``` attribute and will be processed by whatever function you have linked to handle the route (the url) in the form action attribute